# Confirm navigation away from a page using a modal like facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am trying to give a modal confirm box using bootbox.js .Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/tVYQL/1/)**..

My code looks like this, though the problem is the native javascript confirm overshadows my custom confirm box using the [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) plugin:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
   var conf = "All unsaved changes will be lost, are you sure you want to leave the page?";         

   return bootbox.confirm(conf, function(result) 
            {
                return result;
            });
        });
```

Can anyone  tell me what is the problem or help me understand whats going wrong..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do that.  Facebook handles all navigation themselves and does not use `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: So, is there a work around for this :( ?

Comment: Yes; handle all navigations yourself.  (that will not affect the address bar)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery in this case. I have added a class 'confirmation' to the anchor tag for convenience. You can prevent the default behaviour using

```
e.preventDefault
```

Then perform other procedures in the bootbox callback and navigate after the user a provided a response.

```
$('a.confirmation').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);

    bootbox.confirm({
        message: "Are you sure you want to continue?",
        callback: function (result) {
            if(result){ window.location.href = $link.attr('href'); }
        }
    });
});
```